# How to run geosaptial Query in Mongo compass UI?

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query

I have used Mongo Compass.. i want run following geospatial query in Mongo compass

```
db.restaurants.find( { location : { $geoWithin :
                             { $centerSphere :
                                [ [ 88 , 30 ] , 10 / 3963.2 ]
                  } } } )
```

Above Query is actual query. and also i have 2 collection these are restaurants and neighborhoods..

see following image
[image]

Comment: I couldn't run any normal query either. Thumbs down on Compass.

Answer (score 3):

You can also click at any point on the map, hold shift key and drag the pointer to somewhere else. It will build a query for you. So you can use it as a sample for building your own.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Try to enter only the query object into the input field, without `db.restaurants.find...` like so:

```
{ location : { $geoWithin :
                             { $centerSphere :
                                [ [ 88 , 30 ] , 10 / 3963.2 ]
                  } } }
```

Comment: It seems like Compass can't do the calculation `10/3963.2`. It should work if you try it like this: `{location:{$geoWithin:{$centerSphere:[[88,30],0.0002523213565]}}}`

Comment: not working.. apply buttond doesn't enable.. query box still focused on red border in  mongo compass @Rudi

Comment: Yes this is still a issue ! Filter badge is red and button to execute query is disabled. But you can execute the explain plan ! And plan is well calculated ! Crazy !